# NSURLSession : an ssl error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made

Tags: ios, swift3, stripe-payments, nsurlsession, stripe-connect

while calling api using NSURLSession object, we are getting error “an ssl error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made” in **iOS 10.3 iPad**. in all iPhones its working properly.Then what else I have to add to solve this error for iPad.

I have added below keys in
[info.plist file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTQMX.png).

In iPad, I am getting below error each & every time in stripe url.Other Urls are working properlly,

[iPad error ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGenJ.png)

Comment: Need to provide more details like environment..

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you please suggest , which details do you need for this error?

Comment: @HarshShah If this error occurs when sending a request to Stripe's API, I recommend that you reach out to Stripe's support directly at https://support.stripe.com/email. Make sure to include as much information as possible, such as the iOS version, the version of the stripe-ios SDK you're using, and a snippet of the code that triggers the error.